# Reject invalid/unexpected request on sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets

How do I make sure that any invalid or unwanted request that isn't following sockets protocol gets rejected and my socket aren't closed.

Consider a simple example :

```js
var net = require('net');

net.createServer(function(socket) {

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
    });
}).listen(5555);

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

and try visiting that port from browser , and again look at terminal. It produces following error :

```
undefined:1
GET / HTTP/1.1
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token G
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/agauniyal/projects/watch/watch.js:115:35)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

Now I fully agree that visiting that port is a mistake of mine , but closing a socket on different format rather than rejecting that request isn't the ideal way to do it. And what if someone tries to access a webserver at that port only realizing later that there wasn't any at 8080.

So how should I make sure socket isn't closed and rather rejects that request?

**EDIT** : This is possibily happening because I'm calling `JSON.Parse(data.toString())` method on data being received from socket and *http headers* aren't being parsed by that method.

Comment: That example code couldn't possibly cause that error. What is the actual code that you ran when you got that error?

Comment: @DanD. will this help : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85237/monitoring-a-few-servers-api-endpoints? and this : https://github.com/agauniyal/watch. But I'm not doing anything superficial in my code. My code resolves down to this very code.

Comment: @DanD. thanks a lot btw :D , you gave me a good start thanks again :)

Comment: If you get an invalid request. you *should* close the socket. There's something wrong with that client. You don't want to keep talking to him.

Comment: @EJP , I know that , but I still want to reject the request and continue that socket(I have explained why). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Then what you should do is catch the `SyntaxError` that results from `JSON.parse` failing to parse the string.

Comment: @DanD. , or not allow invalid JSON strings to get parsed by it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entire problem rose because I was getting socket response , converting it to string and then parsing it as JSON. Now in my case , I've either to gurantee that incoming data is valid JSON string or find that a browser is sending request to that socket.

For a real-quick-fix , I am extracting first word from incoming data and checking it to be 'GET' ( which a browser sends ) , and if it evaluates to true , just doing nothing else proceeding as I was earlier. Catching JSON.parse error is better solution too.